# Which Perl modules are good for writing a RESTful web API client?

Tags: perl, rest, module

I am going to be writing an application that does a bit of computation on data it gets from a RESTful web service and outputs to a text file and/or HTML page.  The web service is XML over HTTP. I have done a simple proof of concept with LWP::Simple and XML::Simple, but it's all a bit ad-hoc.

Can anyone recommend some Perl modules or best practice for interacting with RESTful web services in this way? Is there one module that will take care of all the details for me (making request + handling response) or is the problem domain too general for that?

Note the web service is all XML over HTTP, though I expect to have to use HTTP GET, POST and HEAD eventually. I think I have the option of requesting JSON instead of XML if it makes thins simpler.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do most everything either with [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl), [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl), [Mojo::UserAgent](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo::UserAgent) or [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize). The REST stuff is just choosing the right URL to send the request too. Once you get the response, there are plenty of modules on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) to handle XML or JSON. I particularly like Mojo since it comes with its own JSON and DOM parsers and tools.

Answer (score 3):

[REST::Client](http://search.cpan.org/~mcrawfor/REST-Client-171/lib/REST/Client.pm) is nice. Atlassian has a [Writing a REST Client in Perl](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FECRUDEV/Writing+a+REST+Client+in+Perl) article.

Comment: I also prefer REST::Client over the other mentioned ones. It has a very lean and easy interface. Behind the scene it is built on LWP::UserAgent and gives access to its configs for special cases. It has some support for XML bodies built in. You most likely want to combine it with "JSON" (module) and WWW::Form::UrlEncoded.

Answer (score -1):

Best  is to use REST:: Client
Or 
For non production, you can make use of curl (unix command) in Perl.
eg:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    $\="\n";
    $s=`curl -s --request GET --url https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search`;
    print $s;
```

Comment: You can make use of PHP or anything else inside Perl for that matter. This really doesn't provide an answer to the question and offers a very dirty solution.

Comment: That's why i said, REST::Client module. the curl solution is for just workaround/dirty solution.